# Save object without releasing lock?

Tags: hibernate, grails, pessimistic-locking

Let's say I have a domain object which was selected with "lock:true", or simply locked afterwards. 
Is there a way to save() it's state to the database without releasing the lock? (As I understaind, the default behavior is that save() releases the lock.)

I have a long (time-wise) function with many operations which should lock the object during the whole execution, however since some of the parts of the function can fail I would like to save the object's state during execution at certain points.

Answer (score 1):

Successful `save()` returns the instance itself, you can `lock()` that again if you are not worried about the infinitesimal chance of a fetch while update.

`domain.save()?.lock()`